# Executing a long insert statement through JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a backup file structured as INSERT statements. My approach was writing a method to load theses statements from the file and use JDBC template to execute them.

```
public void restoreFile(File f) throws Exception {
    LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(f, "UTF-8");
    try {
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String insertStatement = it.nextLine();
            if (!insertStatement.startsWith("--") && !insertStatement.isEmpty()) {
                insertStatement = insertStatement.replace(";", "");
                executeSqlStatement(insertStatement);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        it.close();
    }
}

public void executeSqlStatement(String sqlStatement) throws Exception {

    PreparedStatementCreator statement = new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
            return statement;
        }
    };
    getJdbcTemplate().update(statement);
}
```

This seemed to work fine in a few cases. However, some of the values I'm inserting are giant XML strings (some XMLs being above 10K characters).

When I run the update function, I get the following error with several files:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01704: string literal too long
```

On the other hand, if I run the same script in SQL Developer, this error doesn't happen.

I'm aware that I should be using the prepared statement with bind vars but since the demand was having the file stored as inserts, I'd rather not having to parse the entire file. I want to simply execute each line as it is.

Is there a workaround for this?

EDIT: Also, how does SQL Developer deal with these long string literals?

Comment: What library are you using to execute your SQL? Its very odd to see something like PreparedStatementCreator.  I suspect you may not have the issue you think you have. The error message specifically refers to a string literal being too long. I think you should print the sql you are trying to execute and run it manually.  Something to keep in mind is batching updates can substantially speed up insert times.  Whether you use jdbc batching or just concatenating insert strings.  If its a data load its not a terrible plan.

Comment: How long is "long"? You need to be precise.

Comment: you can not use a string that is longer than 4000 characters otherwise you have to bind variables in a prepared statement.

Comment: @Deadron I'm using org.springframework.jdbc.core but I don't see why it's odd (you might find it unusual but that's absolutely not the issue). What do you mean by printing the SQL and running it manually? As already mentioned, I did try to execute the script using SQL Developer and it works fine, which gives me the impression that JDBC may have restrictions nonexistent in Oracle's SQL IDE. I didn't think this could be the issue because since Oracle is the developer of everything here mentioned, one may expect a decent integration among these systems.

Comment: @eaolson edited, thank you!

Comment: @jojo_Berlin so you're saying that there is absolutely no way of running a plain SQL script using JDBC (no matter the size of the string)? I found a couple of libraries that promise to do so, but I'm trying to avoid bloating my project with more database connectivity features.

Comment: @Lucas at least it seems like it. It could be possible that the liberies use prepared statements under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here comes the hackatron:

```
public void executeSqlStatement(String sqlStatement) throws Exception {

    PreparedStatementCreator statement = new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection)
                    throws SQLException {
            List<String> params = new ArrayList<>();
            if (sqlStatement.length() >= 4000) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(([^'\n]|'')+)'");
                Matcher m = pattern.matcher(sqlStatement);
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                while (m.find()) {
                    params.add(m.group(1).replace("''", "'"));
                    m.appendReplacement(sb, "?");
                }
                m.appendTail(sb);
                sqlStatement = sb.toString();
            }
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
            for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); ++i) {
                statement.setString(1 + i, params.get(i));
            }
            return statement;
        }
    };
    getJdbcTemplate().update(statement);
}
```

As you can see: it attempts to shrink larger SQLs by extracting the string literals.

Comment: It seems that this workaround is the only way to solve my issue. I made a few tweaks to your code and it is working fine.